How to reuse a generic static method's parameter in a generic function?
Here I try to reuse Omit<T, 'id'> on a generic function:
class Model{
   static create<T extends Model>(a: Omit<T, 'id'>): number{
        return 0;
    }

    id = 0;
    title = 'test';
}

class Child extends Model{
    child = true;
}


function createModel<T extends typeof Model>(model: T, data: Parameters<T['create']>[0]) : InstanceType<T> {
    return {} as InstanceType<T>;
}

const instance = createModel(Child, {title: 'test', child :true }); // what child props here as the second arg


Playground
Using Parameters<T.func<InstanceType<T>>> gives:
Cannot access 'T.func' because 'T' is a type, but not a namespace. Did you mean to retrieve the type of the property 'func' in 'T' with 'T["func"]'?(2713)

Using Parameters<T['create']<InstanceType<T>>> gives
Parameter 'InstanceType' implicitly has an 'any' type.

PLUS invalid syntax with createModel having like 6 params
Any way to reuse the parameter without introducing a common external type?

It's unclear what your test function is supposed to be doing. But most likely, it should not be generic over some typeof Model, it should be generic over a Model?

@Bergi i should be able to pass the class itself and call its create method

@Bergi corrected the code for more clarity

I still don't get it. What is createModel actually doing? Is it calling Mode.create<T>()? Why does it receive a class as its first argument?

@Bergi it's bound to a real case very loosely, i just use this test code to understand how I could reuse Omit<T, 'id'> extracting it from the parameter type

I think this might not be possible at all, see e.g. Getting the return type of a function which uses generics or How to get return type from type of generic function?, especially if you want to make the function generic over the type of the class. Only Parameters<typeof Model.create<Child>>[0] gets somewhat close to Omit<Child, 'id'>.

How does create() know about the "current" type? Child.create() accepts any Omit<Model, "id">, not just Omit<Child, "id">. If you want to change that you need to fix create() before you even get to createModel.  Possibly you want something like this approach but I don't see what {} as T is going to do there. It's not obvious to me what the goal is here and the implementation doesn't provide any insight. Please [edit] to clarify what you're doing and show how things work before calling createModel().

@jcalz the current type is passed as a class as the first parameter. for me it's obvious that you can parameterize the static method with InstanceType<T> (T = Child) in our case. I guess Typescript just doesn't support this syntax

I'm not asking about createModel(), I'm asking about Model.create(). It accepts T extends Model but that doesn't mean that T is the "current" type. Child.create() accepts any Model, not necessarily Child(). InstanceType is not part of it.  Please [edit] to explain what Model.create() does, especially since it... returns a number, which is... what is that? What is it creating?

Since func is a static method it doesn't exist on an instance of Model
I think this is what you are looking for.
function test<T extends typeof Model>(model: T, data: Parameters<T['func']>[0]) : T {
    return {} as T;
}

Edit
Updated answer based on clarifications on the question.
class Model {
  static create<T extends Model>(a: Omit<T, "id">): number {
    return 0;
  }

  id = 0;
  title = "test";
}

class Child extends Model {
  child = true;
}

declare function createInstance<T extends typeof Model>(
  model: T,
  data: Parameters<typeof Model.create<InstanceType<T>>>[0],
): InstanceType<T>;

const t = createInstance(Child, { title: "test", child: true });


Does this do what you want it to do?  https://tsplay.dev/m0Dbxm

this gives the second error

In what scenario do you get this error?    Modifying the playground you provided with my answer I am not seeing that error. https://tsplay.dev/N57O5W

you missed the generic parameters of test() passing as a generic parameter to the static method, if you will try test(Child, {child: true}) you wil get an error https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/?#code/MYGwhgzhAECyD2ATApiA3gWAFDVxALmPgJbDQBmArgHbAA8AKtMgB77LWIwIogB8ACjAAuaAHkAtsXyMANNADkxRAr4BKUdUoSARsgBOmHLhO59yfJX3VoABgDc2UwF9sTk8ugBeO4+O4SfBBkb0V2AgU-VyxsUEgYAGEAC2IQRGY2Di44JFQjU2AUtND8fUpkKLcYrCpaEngbcJkmVnZOGHwATwAHZHhyHN5BCVyQUQZ5RCIRaAAFMH0wCQsDCEYAbQVa4AUAXT512121aHHofJNzS2tz52hIaAZK6uAGgmh8EuQCAWTUxHkaECwVECiaCnkhX+olK5Wcaj8QA

Modified answer based on clarifications of criteria.
